# How to debug a pipelined function in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a PL/SQL package in oracle database which contains a pipelined function named **FN_GET_USERINFO_ROWS** as bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_USERINFO AS

  TYPE TY_USERINFO_RECORD IS RECORD( U_ID    VARCHAR2(50),
                                     U_NAME  VARCHAR2(50),
                                     DOB     DATE);     
  TYPE TY_USERINFO_TABLE IS TABLE OF TY_USERINFO_RECORD;


  FUNCTION FN_GET_USERINFO_ROWS(P_USER_ID IN NUMBER)
    RETURN TY_USERINFO_TABLE PIPELINED;

END PKG_USERINFO;
```

And I'm running following test script to test pipelined **FN_GET_USERINFO_ROWS** at **[PL/SQL Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL_Developer)** (*File->New->Test Window*)

```
declare
  result PKG_USERINFO.TY_USERINFO_TABLE;
begin
  -- calling pipelined function
  result := PKG_USERINFO.FN_GET_USERINFO_ROWS(P_USER_ID => :P_USER_ID);
end;
```

But it is showing following error:

> ORA-06550: line 28, column 12: PLS-00653: aggregate/table functions
>   are not allowed in PL/SQL scope

How can I debug a pipelined function using **[PL/SQL Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL_Developer)** ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the ways is to create a block with `FOR-SELECT-LOOP` and put a breakpoint into the function or just log contents for each fetched row (depends on what you mean by debugging). So you can separate each `PIPE ROW` execution and see its results.
 Then in **PL/SQL Dev** choose *File->Open->TestScript* and run the block from opened window.

```
DECLARE      
  result pkg_userinfo.ty_userinfo_table;
BEGIN
  -- we call pipelined functions like this

  FOR rec IN (SELECT *
                FROM TABLE (pkg_userinfo.fn_get_userinfo_rows(:P_USER_ID))
            -- WHERE rownum < 2
            -- uncomment this line and vary amount of fetched rows
             )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('another step : ' || rec.u_id);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Also I advise you to debug variants when `NO_DATA_NEEDED` is being thrown. To do it add `WHERE` clause limiting number of rows.